# Google Apps Script add folders for users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

We have a set of shared folders that all members of staff need to have access to. They have been invited, but Drive does not automatically add the folder to their "My Drive" as they were invited as a group (100+).

I am trying to create a script that will automatically add these folders to their Drive. Currently I have got that working when the script is executed as the individual.

```
  var root = DocsList.getRootFolder();
  var folderIds = ["folderID", "folderID2"];
  folderIds.map( function(id) { DocsList.getFolderById(id).addToFolder(root) } );
```

This works, however with around 100 users, all with very little knowledge of computers and accessing via an iPad, the ideal would be for me as an admin to execute this for each user.

Is there a way I can use the `UserManager` API to do this? That way I can quickly add the folders to the right users, depending on their groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this from apps script unless you make each user run the script.
To do that you can publish it and run it frrom a site but users will need to aprove the script.

If you want to impersonate the user (see impersonation in drive api) you can do so with drive api from appengine which requires 2legged oauth and such. From there u can run it without user intervention.

Comment: Thanks, for now I am going with the Apps Script, whilst I work on an impersonation method for the future. Thanks.